# Events from gridview to textbox do not match the result in textbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, events, gridview, textbox

should the textbox date (txt.DTE) be empty instead of containing the date from the previous date that I did double click cell gridview. Is there a solution or is my code wrong?.

Note : I use visual studio 2010

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellDoubleClick
        x = DataGridView1.Rows.IndexOf(DataGridView1.CurrentRow)
        txtCODE.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
        Dim dte = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(1).Value.ToString()
        If dte <> Nothing Then
            txtDTE.Text = CDate(dte)
        End If
        txtQTY.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(2).Value.ToString()
        txtPRICE.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(3).Value.ToString()
    End Sub
```

[image: view gridview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `else` code in your `if` clause to clear the value of the `txtDTE` if the date column is blank.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellDoubleClick
        x = DataGridView1.Rows.IndexOf(DataGridView1.CurrentRow)
        txtCODE.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
        Dim dte = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(1).Value.ToString()
        If dte <> Nothing Then
            txtDTE.Text = CDate(dte)
        else
            ' CLEAR txtDTE if dt = nothing
            txtDTE.clear()
        End If
        txtQTY.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(2).Value.ToString()
        txtPRICE.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(3).Value.ToString()
    End Sub
```

**Another advice**:
You can use `e.RowIndex` instead of `DataGridView1.Rows.IndexOf(DataGridView1.CurrentRow)` which also returns the current row index.

Example:

```
x = e.RowIndex()
```

Instead of

```
x = DataGridView1.Rows.IndexOf(DataGridView1.CurrentRow)
```

Comment: for code `x = e.RowIndex()` with `x = DataGridView1.Rows.IndexOf(DataGridView1.CurrentRow)` the function is almost the same and the code from you runs perfectly to bring the textbox date to blank. You made the best solution for me

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71746016/wants-events-in-textbox-with-messagebox-and-not-gridview-filter-state-if-code-is). I have a recent post maybe you can help me