# wants events in textbox with MessageBox and not gridview filter state if code is not found in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, events, gridview, textbox, bindingsource

I want to appear MessageBox and not gridview filter state if code is not found.

```
Dim source1 As New BindingSource()
Private Sub TextBox2_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyDown
        If TextBox2.Text = "" Then
            source1.Filter = ""
            Me.DataGridView1.Refresh()
        Else
            If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
                source1.Filter = "CODE like  '' + '" & TextBox2.Text & "' + '' "
                Me.DataGridView1.Refresh()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

[image: view1]
[image: view2]

Comment: Just to clarify.  You want a message box to appear if no records match the filter criteria?

Comment: @Hursey , yes really and if it is not suitable or not met then gridview is not a state

Comment: So would the BindingSource.Count property help?  Use that to tell you if no records are visible, then show the message box?

Comment: @Hursey , `If source1.Count <= 0 Then MsgBox("No Result Found!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation) End If` I tried with this code but the messagebox appeared but it remained in a filter state.

Comment: @Jack after prompting the messagebox what do you want next? Do you want to clear the filter of source1?

Comment: @TheCoolCat ,yes right after messagebox then clear filter and clear textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another `if statement` inside the else then check if the `source1` has rows, if rows <= 0 then clear the filter and the textbox.

**UPDATED**

```
Dim source1 As New BindingSource()
Private Sub TextBox2_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyDown
      If TextBox2.Text = "" Then
          source1.Filter = ""
          Me.DataGridView1.Refresh()
      Else
          If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
              source1.Filter = "CODE like  '' + '" & TextBox2.Text & "' + '' "
           
               ' If Else Statement to determine the count of your bindingsource
               ' Check the results, if result is less than or equal to 0 
               ' then prompt messagebox and clear the source filter
               If source1.count <= 0
                   source1.Filter = ""
                   TextBox2.Clear()
                   MsgBox("No Result Found!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
               End If
               Me.DataGridView1.Refresh()
          End If
      End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried the code from you yet it doesn't work

Comment: @Jack try testing this again, I updated the code

Comment: your code goes as I want and perfectly

Comment: `The expression contains an invalid string constant: ''' + '' .`  I have a slight error because I tried to input `'` or Apostrophe. how is the solution?. line code error               
`source1.Filter = "CODE like  '' + '" & TextBox2.Text & "' + '' "`

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71764045/event-in-textbox-for-binding-source-filter-gridview-for-string-type-in-vb-net) I've made in the latest post maybe you can help me

Comment: @Jack okay let me check