# event in textbox for binding source filter datagridview for string type in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, events, gridview, textbox, bindingsource

is there a solution for events in the textbox for binding source filters for string types. The example screenshot below with the code "1000*" should appear directly appear cell gridvivew but appears containing the code "1000" and also I tried to input Apostrophe in the textbox there is an error "The expression contains an invalid string constant."

THanks
jack

```
Dim source1 As New BindingSource()
  Private Sub TextBox2_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Back Then
            source1.Filter = ""
            TextBox1.Clear()
            Me.DataGridView1.Refresh()
        Else
            If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
                source1.Filter = "CODE like  '' + '" & TextBox2.Text & "' + '' "

                ' If Else Statement to determine the count of your bindingsource
                ' Check the results, if result is less than or equal to 0 
                ' then prompt messagebox and clear the source filter
                If source1.Count <= 0 Then
                    source1.Filter = ""
                    TextBox2.Clear()
                    MsgBox("No Result Found!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
                End If
                Me.DataGridView1.Refresh()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

[image: Capture01]
[image: Capture02]
[image: The expression contains an invalid string constant.]

Comment: A `DataGridView` is a not a `GridView`.

Comment: What is the point of concatenating two empty strings to your value here: `"CODE like  '' + '" & TextBox2.Text & "' + '' "`? Do you add zero to numbers? Of course you don't, because that would be madness. Why, then, would you concatenate an empty string?

Comment: There is no point calling `Refresh` on the `DataGridView`. That simply redraws the control is if the control is not drawing properly then you have other issues you need to fix.

Comment: You should not be filtering on the `KeyDown` event. At least do it on the `TextChanged` event. You should also use a `Timer` to delay the filter slightly, so that the user can type multiple characters without filtering multiple times.

Comment: I would also recommend using a single `TextBox` to filter and `RadioButtons` to specify whether the match should be full or partial. That is unless you want to be able to filter on both at the same time.

Comment: @user18387401 , for gridview then I'm the one who mistyped

Comment: @user18387401 , `What is the point of concatenating two empty strings to your value here: "CODE like  '' + '" & TextBox2.Text & "' + '' "? Do you add zero to numbers? Of course you don't, because that would be madness. Why, then, would you concatenate an empty string? `. if this is my fault because previously I used it for filters based on contain

Comment: @user18387401,  `There is no point calling Refresh on the DataGridView. That simply redraws the control is if the control is not drawing properly then you have other issues you need to fix. ` means I have to eliminate to control Refresh in datagridview

Comment: @user18387401 , `You should not be filtering on the KeyDown event. At least do it on the TextChanged event. You should also use a Timer to delay the filter slightly, so that the user can type multiple characters without filtering multiple times. ` so I want after typing the code using keypress enter then it automatically appears so is there another solution

Comment: @user18387401 ,`I would also recommend using a single TextBox to filter and RadioButtons to specify whether the match should be full or partial. That is unless you want to be able to filter on both at the same time.` . if this is the case I need a solution and recommendations from you

Comment: I missed that you were testing for the `Enter` key rather than filtering on every key press.

Answer (score 0):

You have used the `LIKE` operator, in which case an asterisk is treated as a wildcard. If you only want full matches and not partial matches then use the equality operator, not the LIKE operator:

```vb
source1.Filter = "CODE = '" & TextBox2.Text & "'"
```

or, preferably:

```vb
source1.Filter = $"CODE = '{TextBox2.Text}'"
```

Comment: `source1.Filter = $"CODE = '{TextBox2.Text}'"` for the second answer solution from you I can't use it because there is a character is not valid and I use visual studio 2010. for the first answer solution to this code `"` that I use why by typing does not appear but if I copy from cell datagridview can appear and if I type code  like this `'` then there is an error "The expression contains an invalid string constant: '''."

Comment: @Jack, I'm not sure why anyone would be using such an old version of VS but, if you are, you can still use the `String.Format` method. The string interpolation that I used in the second example is basically just native language support for that.

Comment: If you might have single quotes in the value then you need to escape them with another single quote, just as you escape a double quote in a VB string with another double quote. This is out of the scope of the question you actually asked in the first place but you can use `String.Replace` to do that.

Comment: for a single quote is already in my post so I want to skip the single quote so that there are no errors. so how is the code and please update also in your answer and if you don't mind add your third answer with the code using `string.format`